# Como manter o nome do arquivo codificado (UTF-8) ao descompactar em R?

Tags: r, utf-8

Estou com problemas para acessar os arquivos de uma pasta compactada. Os nomes dos arquivos contém acentos, mas ao descompactar os nomes são alterados de acordo com a configuração de cada computador que abre e executa o código. Existe alguma maneira de manter o nome do arquivo codificado ao descompactar ou de conseguir acessar os arquivos dessa pasta? Preciso fazer tudo via código do R (versão 4.0.2) no windows 10. Ao executar o seguinte código:

```
dir.create("./federal_highway")
setwd("./federal_highway/")
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(URLencode("https://servicos.dnit.gov.br/dnitcloud/index.php/s/oTpPRmYs5AAdiNr/download"), destfile = "./original/Repositorio.zip", method="auto", mode="wb")
unzip("./original/Repositorio.zip") 
zipfiles <- list.files(path = "./RepositÃ³rio/SNV Bases GeomÃÂ©tricas (2013-Atual) (SHP)", full.names = T, pattern = "*.zip")
```

Ele roda sem erros, mas eu recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
Warning message:
In list.files(path = "./RepositÃ³rio/SNV Bases GeomÃ<U+0083>Â©tricas (2013-Atual) (SHP)",  :
  unable to translate './RepositÃ³rio/SNV Bases GeomÃ<U+0083>Â©tricas (2013-Atual) (SHP)' to native encoding
```

E zipfiles retorna "character(0)"

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o comando dir() para ir montando o o caminho do arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
setwd("./federal_highway/")
repo <- dir("./sf_all_years_original")
repozipfiles <- dir(paste0("./sf_all_years_original/",repo[1]))
SNV <- repozipfiles[3]
dir_repo <- paste0("./sf_all_years_original/",repo[1],"/",SNV,"/")
setwd(dir_repo)

a <- getwd()
zipfiles <- dir(a)
```

Descompactar as pastas zipadas

```
for(i in 1:length(zipfiles)){
  unzip(zipfiles[i])
}
```

Listar somente arquivos shp, por exemplo

```
raw_shapes <- list.files(".", pattern = ".shp", recursive = T, full.names = T)
raw_shapes <- raw_shapes[raw_shapes %nlike% '.xml']
```